# Plot regular 2D graph but add 3rd dimension as heatmap

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Couldn't find what I am asking anywhere, maybe wrong key words. Essentially, I have 3 dimensions in a matrix:

```
> head(info)
        [,1]   [,2]  [,3]
[1,] 8.59645 251944 22.89
[2,] 6.95160 141559 21.35
[3,] 7.43870 131532 22.99
[4,] 8.64467 126688 22.72
[5,] 8.77482 123120 22.17
[6,] 7.22364 122268 24.46
```

I am plotting info[,3] vs info[,2]

```
plot(info[,3], info[,2], type="p", pch=20)
```

[image: Plotting info[,3] vs info[,2]]

And I wanted to color the dots with a heatmap based on info[,1].

I could just do this sort of thing:

```
plot(info[which(info[,1] <= 2),3], info[which(info[,1] <= 2),2], type="p", pch=20, col="black")
lines(info[which(info[,1] >= 2),3], info[which(info[,1] >= 2),2], type="p", pch=20, col="red")
```

[image: plotting based on info[,1]]

But I believe a heatmap would look better.

Any ideas? Thanks,
Adrian

SOLUTION:
Thank you all for the wonderful suggestions! This is what worked:

```
qplot(info[,3], info[,2], colour=info[,1]) + scale_colour_gradient(limits=c(0, 10), low="green", high="red")
```

[image: Solution working!]

Comment: You could use `ggplot2` and use the third column as color. A look at the examples [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_gradient.html) might help.

Comment: Thanks! This worked beautifully: qplot(info[,3], info[,2], colour=info[,1]) + scale_colour_gradient(limits=c(0, 10), low="green", high="red")

Comment: I dont get why you're using `lines` is that a typo? in base graphics, you can also do `cols <- colorRampPalette(c('red','yellow'))(1000)[info[, 1] * 1000]; plot(info[, 3], info[, 2], col = adjustcolor(cols, alpha.f = .3), pch = 19)`

Answer (score 6):

Using `ggplot2` you can color by a third variable

```
## Some sample data
set.seed(0)
x <- rnorm(1000, rep(c(20, 60), each=500), 8)
y <- c(rexp(500, 1/5e4)*1/(abs(x[1:500]-mean(x[1:500]))+runif(1)),
       rexp(500, 1/5e3)*1/(abs(x[501:1000]-mean(x[501:1000]))+runif(1)))
z <- c(sort(runif(1000)))
info <- matrix(c(z,y,x), ncol=3)

## Using ggplot
ggplot(as.data.frame(info), aes(V3, V2, col=V1)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.5) +
  scale_color_gradient(low="red", high="yellow")
```

[image]

If you want to make a heat map, you could use `akima` package to interpolate between your points, and do,

```
library(akima)
dens <- interp(x, y, z,
               xo=seq(min(x), max(x), length=100),
               yo=seq(min(y), max(y), length=100),
               duplicate="median")
filled.contour(dens, xlab="x", ylab="y", main="Colored by z",
               color.palette = heat.colors)
```

[image]